# eBay API call to revise multiple items together

Tags: ebay-api

I can't find an API call in eBay that would allow me to revise multiple items in one call.

I want to revise the price for thousand items, it is absurd to make a call for each of them.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most simple way it's use ReviseInventoryStatus call http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/ReviseInventoryStatus.html
This call allow revise multiple item at once in case you change price/qty

Another possibility it's use Large merchant service API https://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/large-merchant-services